# Add list items to Object & Properties - javaScript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I'm trying to copy specific field data from list items to properties in an object, which appears to be working, however, I have multiple rows of data and the function is pasting the same row every time into my array. I'm obviously missing something, but not sure what. Also, if there is a better way to do this I'm all ears! See code below...

```
function getListData(listName) {
dfd = $.Deferred();
parentId = GetUrlKeyValue("ID", false, location.href);
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
context.load(web);
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
caml.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="LinkID" /><Value Type="Lookup">' + parentId + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
listItems = list.getItems(caml);
context.load(listItems, "Include(ID, Current_x0020_Public_x0020_IP_x0, New_x0020_Public_x0020_IP_x0020_, New_x0020_Assigned_x0020_Public_, Disconnect_x0020_IP_x0020_Subnet)");
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var count = listItems.get_count();
    var arraySubnet = [];
    var PublicSubnet = { current: "", new: "", assigned: "" };
    var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        id = listItem.get_item("ID");
        currentSubnet = listItem.get_item('Current_x0020_Public_x0020_IP_x0');
        newSubnetRequested = listItem.get_item('New_x0020_Public_x0020_IP_x0020_');
        newAssignedSubnet = listItem.get_item('New_x0020_Assigned_x0020_Public_');
        PublicSubnet.current = currentSubnet;
        PublicSubnet.new = newSubnetRequested;
        PublicSubnet.assigned = newAssignedSubnet;
        arraySubnet.push(PublicSubnet);

    } // End while
    console.log(arraySubnet);
    dfd.resolve();
}, function() {
    dfd.reject();
});
return dfd.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not creating "new" `PublicSubnet` instances. Instead you are overriding the one instance you have and adding it multiple times.

Move the line `var PublicSubnet = { current: "", new: "", assigned: "" };` into the `while`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like given below inside your While loop:

```
listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
var PublicSubnet = {
                     current: listItem.get_item('Current_x0020_Public_x0020_IP_x0'),
                     new: listItem.get_item('New_x0020_Public_x0020_IP_x0020_'),
                     assigned: listItem.get_item('New_x0020_Assigned_x0020_Public_')
                   };
arraySubnet.push(PublicSubnet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code snippet as below:

```
var count = listItems.get_count();
var arraySubnet = [];

var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
    id = listItem.get_item("ID");

    currentSubnet = listItem.get_item('Current_x0020_Public_x0020_IP_x0');
    newSubnetRequested = listItem.get_item('New_x0020_Public_x0020_IP_x0020_');
    newAssignedSubnet = listItem.get_item('New_x0020_Assigned_x0020_Public_');
    var PublicSubnet = { current: currentSubnet, new: newSubnetRequested, assigned: newAssignedSubnet };
    arraySubnet.push(PublicSubnet);

} // End while
console.log(arraySubnet);
```

[image]